# pass a variable from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using a JSON string to pass a variable in JavaScript from PHP :

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        {
                $tmp = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'alert_type_id'=>$row['alert_type_id'], 'deviation'=>$row['deviation'], 'threshold_low'=>$row['threshold_low'], 'threshold_high'=>$row['threshold_high']) ;
                $settings[] = $tmp ;
        }

        echo '{"data":'.json_encode($settings).'}' ;
```

in Javascript, i am using the following snippet :

```
console.log( result ) ;                
var json = eval('('+ result +')') ;
```

and what appears in the Console is the following error :

```
1{"data":[{"id":"1","alert_type_id":"1","deviation":null,"threshold_low":"20","threshold_high":"80"}]}

SyntaxError: Expected token ')'
```

Could you please help me overcome this issue please ?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that line of code isn't valid.

Write in the console:

```
'(1{"data":[{"id":"1","alert_type_id":"1","deviation":null,"threshold_low":"20","threshold_high":"80"}]})'
```

As this is what you're passing to the `eval` function. I should give you the same error.

If you want to save that string in a variable you need to adjust it a bit:

```
eval('var x =' + result);
```

Anyway It looks like you're doing something wrong, check again why do you need ti use the "evil" `eval`.

Comment: isn't that the same as : '('+ result +')' i am sorry but i am not getting what's wrong

Comment: @user690182. No it's not. it will just run the string "command" in side `()`. What are you trying to do with the `json`?

Comment: thank you, i wrote what you just said in PHP : echo '('.'{"data":'.json_encode($settings).'}'.')' ; and everything is ok now :) thank you

Comment: @user690182. I can't find where i said it... Any way you should accept an answer if you got one. **:=)**

Comment: Don't use eval() use a JSON parser to get the data as stated in the other answers.

Comment: @Guumaster. Didn't you read the part which I recommended not to use `eval`???

Comment: sorry, I stopped reading after eval() ^_^. +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP, you probably want to use `json_encode` for encoding all of your data:

```
$result = array(
  'data' => json_encode($settings)
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Second, in your javascript, `eval` is rarely (never) a good idea. From Douglas Crockford's style guide:

> The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript. Avoid it.

Instead, you probably want to use `JSON.parse()` to rebuild the result returned by the server:

```
console.log(result) ;                
var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(resultObj);
```

If your code is still broken, you might want to double-check your PHP to make sure it isn't spewing out any output beyond the `json_encode` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Something is outputting a "1" in front of your json string. Javascript is unable to resolve that properly during eval().