# Update php session var while staying on the same page?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

First of all: This question is not a duplicate, don't close this like my previous question. I've looked at most questions about sessions.

In this case I am looking to update `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` while remaining on the same page.

A user can choose a client, this client will be stored in `$_SESSION['selectedClient']`. At some point a user may want to select another client. So for that, I've tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['clientEmail'])){
        $_SESSION['selectedClient'] = $_POST['clientEmail'];
    }
```

Except this doesnt work. This would set the initial selected client and should also update a next selection.

If you have selected the first client and you're trying to select a new client.
These are the outputs:

`_POST['clientEmail'] = >lol@lol.com<`
`_SESSION['selectedClient'] = >lol@lol.com<`

after refresh:

`_POST['clientEmail'] = ><`
`_SESSION['selectedClient'] = >login@login.com<`

Clarification: login@login.com is the first selected client. lol@lol.com new selected client.
**Note 1**: `session_start()` has been set.
**Note 2**: tried unsetting `$_SESSION['selectedClient']` and then assigning the new post.
**Note 3**: [How to use store and use session variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages) Doesnt have the answer I am looking for, been on this question multiple times.

Comment: If you're staying on the same page, does that mean you're using AJAX?

Comment: Where does `login@login.com` come from?

Comment: Use Ajax for do that [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650930/how-to-update-session-variable-with-jquery-ajax-is-it-even-possible)

Comment: @Barmar No, what I mean with that is: the form action leads to home.php, here is all the code for this page. at the bottom of home.php I include the html page. The application is built through the MVC principle.

Those emails are just test emails to test the functioning of the client selection

Comment: What is the new client you're trying to select?

Comment: login@login.com is the first selected client. After that I'm trying to select lol@lol.com

Comment: So `lol@lol.com` is the new client, but then the session is going back to the first client?

Comment: Nothing does that by itself, you must have some other code that's changing the session variable.

Comment: @Barmar Thats correct. It doesnt save the update. after I refresh the page it's back to login@login.com

Comment: How are you refreshing page?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['clientEmail'])) will only be true when you submit. Looks like there is problem in code.

Comment: First I tried to just click in the url-bar and press enter again to avoid re-submitting the form. Secondly I tried to `echo '<script>document.location=\'\?p=home\';</script>';`